# Issue reading a file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file, input

i am creating a program to read the .dxf file of autodesk.
i am encountering a problem while reading strings.

when i use :

```
string acad;
fstream f;
f.open(name);
f >> acad
```

if the string is "chamfer" it works perfect.
but if the string is "a & b" it is able to read only upto a.
since the file format follows a pattern i am using `while` loop.

example from a file:

```
  9           //loop 1
$DWGCODEPAGE  //loop 1
  3           //looop 1
ANSI_1252     //looop 1
  9           //loop 2
$LASTSAVEDBY  //loop 2
  1           //loop 2
sam & tom     //loop 2
9             //loop 3 
$INSBASE      //loop 3
 10           //loop 3
0.0           //loop 3
```

as you can see sometimes there may not be any space as in "ANSI_1252" & sometimes there may be spaces as in "sam & tom".
how can i generalise the code so that the whole string in a line is stored along with the spaces, if any.
please forget about the spaces in the beginning of each line, i am using `ws` for that.
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>>` operator reads words delimited by space, when used with a string parameter. If you want to read lines of characters, you should use `getline()` instead.

Comment: getline() requires a char * arg, but i want to store the data in string data type

Comment: wrong: "Notice that the istream extraction operations use whitespaces as separators, therefore this operation will only extract what can be considered a word from the stream. To extract entire lines of text, refer to the string overload of global function getline." http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/

Comment: @SirDarius
wow you have solved my problem so easily.
thank you!
can i use newline character as a delimitor?

Comment: the newline character is the default delimiter for getline, hence the name "get line".